# PHP classes used within classes?

Tags: php, class

I understand that `$something->function();` is calling a function within a class but what does `$something->somethingelse->function();` mean?

Comment: Are you sure it's `$something->$somethingelse->function();` and not `$something->somethingelse->function();` or `$something->somethingelse()->function();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `$something->somethingelse->function()`.

It means that a property of `$something` named `$somethingelse` is another object that has the method `function()`.

```
$something = new Class1();
$something->somethingelse = new Class2();  // Class2 has the "function()" method


// Now I can call...
$something->somethingelse->function();
```

Comment: OH, so what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @user658911 The purpose is to have the functionality of that object inside that class. It's called the [dependency injection](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/) pattern.

Comment: So would you use this for using a database object like $addusers->db = $db; where $db is a class.

Comment: @user yup, for example, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

you can say it like this:

```
class foo {
  public $bar;
}

class bar {
  public $baz;
}

class baz {
  function blip() { echo "Hello World"; }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar = new bar(); // setting bar to new object
$foo->bar->baz = new baz(); // setting baz to new object
$foo->bar->baz->blip(); // calling the blip function
```

Comment: I changed it around, so it works exactly the same. I wasnt aware that var was deprecated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class of the instance $something contains an instance variable called $somethingelse which is also an object (instance of a class).

It's considered a bad practice (see [Law of Demeter on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

A nice explanation of the [Law of Demeter is on c2.com](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter) of Peter Van Rooijen is:

> You can play with yourself.
>
> You can play with your own toys (but you can't take them apart),
>
> You can play with toys that were given to you.
>
> And you can play with toys you've made yourself.

That is in plain English:

> Your method can call other methods in its class directly
>
> Your method can call methods on its own fields directly (but not on the fields' fields)
>
> When your method takes parameters, your method can call methods on those parameters directly.
>
> When your method creates local objects, that method can call methods on the 
>           local objects.

BUT

> One should not call methods on a global object
>
> One should not have a chain of messages a.getB().getC().doSomething() in some class other than a's class.

Another interesting read is [Law of Demeter Revisited](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeterRevisited) for a less strict approach.

Comment: I disagree that it's bad practice generally. Patterns like [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) couldn't work without it

Comment: dependency injection though, is about injecting the instance of $somethingelse in $something, without having to create it with new inside $something (that would cement the dependency). It's not about exposing those dependencies, what should be the "private parts" of a class. You can make it write only with a setter.